# I need to compare my date and time with mobile date and time?

Tags: android, datetime, android-emulator, datepicker, compare

For a task remainder application i need to compare the mobile current date and time with my task and time.
How this is possible??

Comment: What do you mean, mobile time and task time?

Comment: It would help if we knew the format of your task date and time.

Answer (score 2):

convert your task time to long value suppose x1, and get system time via `System.currentTimeMillis()` sppose x2.

compare them like one compare long values..

Answer (score 1):

Use [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

Get an instance of `Calendar`, set hours, minutes, date etc, and then use `getTimeInMillis()` which you need to compare with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Also, you might want to take a look at [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to actually schedule some action to some moment of time.